# Como puedo redirigir la entrada en c++ para llenar un objeto y despues mostrar un menu para realizar operaciones sobre un objeto

Tags: c++, entrada

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void funcion() {
        string linea;
        while (getline(cin, linea)) {
            cout << linea << endl;
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        int a;
        funcion();
        
        cin >> a;
        return 0;
    }
```

Quiero recupera un  archivo de entrada  que contendrá la información correspondiente para a partir de su procesamiento se llena la  la clase en operación.

c://nombre.exe < entrada.txt

Una vez ingresado todos los cursos, el programa continúa presentando el menú para que se puedan realizar las demás operaciones previamente programadas.

Answer (score 0):

*Creo* que no es posible dejar de redirigir la entrada o salida de un programa si se hace desde la consola.

Si estás ejecutando el programa desde Linux, encontré que puedes [redirigir un archivo y seguir ingresando información por teclado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28536051/13419694) con el siguiente comando:

```
cat archivo - | programa
```

Si buscas una solución independiente del terminal, sugiero que abras el archivo directamente desde tu programa para no perder el control. Puedes pasarlo por parámetros si es necesario. Por ejemplo:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ifstream archivo;
    istream *in = cin;
    if (argc >= 2) {
        archivo.open(argv[1]);
        in = &archivo;
    }

    int a;
    funcion();
    
    *in >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te he escrito un ejemplo, basado en lo tú pregunta. Espero que te sea útil. Espero que sea lo que andas buscando en código de C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Se crea una clase llamada Cursos
class Cursos
{
    private:
        string tema_curso = "";
        string codigo_curso = "";
    public:
        void datos_curso();
        void cambiar_datos_curso();
        void mostrar_datos_curso();
};

void Cursos::datos_curso()
{
    cout << "Dime el tema del curso: ";
    cin >> this->tema_curso;
    cin.get();
    cout << "Dime el codigo del curso: ";
    cin >> this->codigo_curso;    
}

void Cursos::cambiar_datos_curso()
{
    cout << "El tema del curso anterior es: " << this->tema_curso << endl;
    cout << "Dime el nuevo tema del curso: ";
    cin >> this->tema_curso;
    cin.get();
    cout << "El codigo del curso anterior es: " << this->codigo_curso << endl;
    cout << "Dime el nuevo codigo del curso: ";
    cin >> this->codigo_curso;        
}

void Cursos::mostrar_datos_curso()
{
    cout << "El tema del curso es: " << this->tema_curso << endl;
    cout << "El codigo del curso es: " << this->codigo_curso << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Cursos curso_nuevo;
//Mediante sus métodos se rellena los datos del objeto curso_nuevo.

    curso_nuevo.datos_curso();
    curso_nuevo.mostrar_datos_curso();
    curso_nuevo.cambiar_datos_curso();
    curso_nuevo.mostrar_datos_curso();
    return 0;
}
```